# How To Set Text In An EditText

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

How can I set the text of an EditText?

Comment: i want to set text in edit text is it possible

Answer (score 319, accepted):

If you check the docs for [`EditText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html), you'll find a `setText()` method. It takes in a `String` and a [`TextView.BufferType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.BufferType.html). For example:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
editText.setText("This sets the text.", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

It also inherits `TextView`'s `setText(CharSequence)` and `setText(int)` methods, so you can set it just like a regular `TextView`:

```
editText.setText("Hello world!");
editText.setText(R.string.hello_world);
```

Comment: `EditText.BufferType.EDITABLE`?

Comment: No, `EditText` extends `TextView`; `TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE` is the correct constant.

Comment: What might confuse a newbie is that setText actually takes a CharSequence and a BufferType. So it's useful to remember that Strings are CharSequence's

Comment: Why does android.text.Editable exist or, better yet, why are normal developers supposed to navigate around it instead of EditText exposing an void setText(CharSequence) method?

Comment: @MarceloLacerda It does expose `setText(CharSequence)`, from its superclass `TextView`. So I'm not really sure why is this the most upvoted & accepted answer?

Comment: It's been so long that I have asked this question that I have no idea what the original problem was. My best guess is that whatever I've found it awkward before got fixed in a new release of the API.

Comment: It's true, a simple setText("String") works for me too. Not sure if there are any issues with that.

Answer (score 27):

if you are using kotlin then it is gonna give you error if you are doing it like

```
editText.text = "some string"
```

just use it like

```
editText.setText("some string")
```

Answer (score 23):

```
String string="this is a text";
editText.setText(string)
```

I have found String to be a useful Indirect Subclass of CharSequence

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html       find setText(CharSequence text)

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html

Comment: Note all Strings are CharSequences, so this one works, but a raw CharSequence is not a String.  If you have a raw CharSequence and REQUIRE a String, you need to call myCharSequence.toString() to get the official String.  Not needed to know for THIS application, but sometimes elsewhere this is necessary.

Answer (score 6):

```
String text = "Example";
EditText edtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtText);
edtText.setText(text);
```

Check it out `EditText` accept only String values  if necessary convert  it to string.

If int, double, long value, do:

```
String.value(value);
```

Answer (score 6):

**This is the solution in Kotlin**

```
val editText: EditText = findViewById(R.id.main_et_name)
    editText.setText("This is a text.")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set `android:text="your text"`;

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/intro_name"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to set text at design time in `xml` file just simple `android:text="username"` add this property.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtUsername"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="username"/>
```

If you want to set text programmatically in Java

```
EditText edtUsername = findViewById(R.id.edtUsername);
edtUsername.setText("username");
```

and in `kotlin` same like java using getter/setter

```
edtUsername.setText("username")
```

But if you want to use `.text` from principle then

```
edtUsername.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("username")
```

because of `EditText.text` requires an `editable` at firstplace not `String`

Answer (score 3):

Use +, the string concatenation operator:

```
 ed = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.box);
    int x = 10;
    ed.setText(""+x);
```

or use

```
String.valueOf(int):
ed.setText(String.valueOf(x));
```

or use

```
Integer.toString(int):
ed.setText(Integer.toString(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
editTextObject.setText(CharSequence)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Declare the `EditText in the xml file`
2. Find the `EditText` in the activity
3. Set the text in the `EditText`

Answer (score 1):

Solution in Android Java:

1. Start your EditText, the ID is come to your xml id.

   ```
   EditText myText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_text_id);
   ```
2. in your OnCreate Method, just set the text by the name defined.

   ```
   String text = "here put the text that you want"
   ```
3. use setText method from your editText.

   ```
   myText.setText(text); //variable from point 2
   ```