# assigning value to a textfield in Android application?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How To Set Text In An EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590957/how-to-set-text-in-an-edittext)

how can we assign value to a textfield in android application?

Comment: Android dosent have textfield, make sure either it should be `EditText` or `TextView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TextView.setText("Your Value Here");` to set a value into your TextView (we call it TextView in Android instead of TextField) on the other note, were you into BlackBerry development before this?

Comment: thank u for the answer..i was in windows mobile development before.

Comment: Ohh Okay.. Do check this out. `TextView` is where you normally put text for display. it won't let the user edit the text. If you have to use the latter feature, use `EditText` instead. although the method to put some value in it will be the same. i.e. `EditText.setText("Your Text");` . Do test and revert with the effects.