# EditText getText but not showing

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a edit text and button

```
EditText edit=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
Toast.makeText(context,edit.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
edit.setText("hello");
}
}
```

but when i click the button i can get the toast with "hello"(the text of the edittext)
but the edittext is empty. is it a bug?

(edit) this is my full code
    finding = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtfindings);
    finding.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
.setTitle("Findings")
.setMultiChoiceItems(
CustomDialog.service.getFindingsArray(), // array of string ex(cd,hard drive,motherboard)
_selectionsFindings, // boolean array size=size of findingsarray
new DialogSelectionClickHandler()) // set click handler on checkbox
.setPositiveButton("OK",
new DialogButtonClickHandler() //set button click
).create()
.show();
}
});

public class DialogSelectionClickHandler implements
DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int clicked,boolean selected) {
} }

public class DialogButtonClickHandler implements
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int clicked) {
        switch (clicked) {
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
            printSelectedFinding();//call the function
            break;
        }
    }
}

protected void printSelectedFinding() {
    String textfinding = "";
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(finding
            .getText().toString().split(","))); 
    if (!finding.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        if (!finding.getText().toString().substring(finding.getText().toString().length() - 1,
        finding.getText().toString().length()).equalsIgnoreCase(",")) {
            textfinding = ",";   //check if last character is == ,
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < CustomDialog.service.getFindingsArray().length; i++) {
        if (_selectionsFindings[i]  //check which item is checked
                && !values.contains(CustomDialog.service.getFindingsArray()[i].trim())) { // check if edittext contains the text
            textfinding += CustomDialog.service.getFindingsArray()[i] + ","; // concatinate string
        }
    }
     finding.append(textfinding); // this where error happens finding is an edittext ex(textfinding = hard drive) finding should have "hard drive"
                    // but it is not displayed but when i use       getText() i can get "hard drive"
}
```

Comment: try edit.getText().tostring()

Comment: yes that is what i am doing.sorry i edit my question

Comment: the issue could be because of sudden change of the text to HELLO, toast usually gets visible after a while so in the mean time it gets the changed value of HELLO and shows that, you need to make some kind of stay between two

Comment: the issue is in the edittext.i can get the text of edittext but the word "hello" is not showing even i edit.setText("hello");

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Set Text In An EditText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590957/how-to-set-text-in-an-edittext)

Comment: it is different because i am able to use getText() and having an output of "hello" but in my widget "hello" is not present

Comment: Your code shouldn't work unless you have set edit as final. I feel there might be some other overlooked issue(duplicate variable?)

Comment: i double checked it already no final no double variable. i dont get what i am doing wrong. it is so confusing because i can use getText but the text is not visible -.-

Comment: you have to setText before you show the toast, then it wont be blank

Comment: it is the same if i click the button several times after the first click the edittext should contain "hello" but it is not happening

Comment: give us your full code if you can.

Comment: what is edittext BACKGROUND AND TEXT COLOR!!!!?

Comment: i jst have white textcolor

Answer (score 3):

> when i click the button i can get the toast with "hello"(the text of
>   the edittext) but the edittext is empty. is it a bug?

You are setting text in editText by

```
 edit.setText("hello");
```

Try it with removing it.

So your code should :

```
EditText edit=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
Toast.makeText(context,edit.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//edit.setText("hello"); <====== comment this line and check
}
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the word "hello" is not showing even i edit.setText("hello"); it

Comment: What is the result after implement my suggestion ?

Comment: it is dynamic but i still post the xml of my listviw

Comment: @KerPPag edit your question and put xml code in question. Not in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText edit=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
edit.setText("hello");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),edit.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
```

now should work..
cheerz

Comment: toast is working problem is edittext even i setText("hello"); it is still blank

Comment: actually it is dynamic.i put it in a listview

Comment: give us your full code, including the adapter if you are using this inside one. Possible that recycling views is making it appear blank.

Comment: list view item button click event?

Comment: try this tutorial http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/02/muftitouch-listview-multi-click.html

Comment: @hypd09 i have edited my question that is my listview adapter

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.edittext;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText edit;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edit=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),edit.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        edit.setText("hello");
        }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="74dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```