# android setText

Tags: android, settext

I want to calculate the circumference of a circle and put the results in a TextView.

```
   public void hesapla1(View v){

        double pi = 3.14;
        double yari = R.id.e1;

        double alan = pi * Math.pow(yari,2);

        sonuc1.setText((int) alan);

    }
```

Comment: Ask questions in English, even if it's bad. At least try, otherwise no one can understand you here.

Comment: Please provide the "Stopping Error", what's the exception stack trace that you are getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Set Text In An EditText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590957/how-to-set-text-in-an-edittext)

Answer (score 2):

You can only set a `String` value in a `TextView`:

`sonuc1.setText(String.valueOf(alan));`