# How to set up this row in XML?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

I am trying to display a `RecyclerView` inside a `DialogFragment` and I can't get the row-item XML to work right.

I am trying to display something like this:

```
TEXTVIEW1 EDITTEXT TEXTVIEW2
```

where `TEXTVIEW1` takes up 1/2th of the width, `EDITTEXT` takes up 1/4th of the width by default, and `TEXTVIEW2` takes up 1/4th of the width (the rest of it).

I stuck these three `Views` inside a horizontal `LinearLayout`. I gave each `View` a `layout_height` of `wrap_content` and a `layout_width` of `0dp` and then I assigned `layout_weight` values to `2, 1, 1` respectively.

However it doesn't display as expected. After I populate all the rows with data and text, the `EditText` widths seem to wrap to their values instead of taking up the quarter portion I designated.

How do I fix this?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="starttext"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="14.0"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="endingtext"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

My adapter:

```
public class SpecialobjectHistoryRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SpecialobjectHistoryRecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {
    public static final String TAG = SpecialobjectRecyclerViewAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private List<SpecialobjectHistory> mSpecialobjectHistoryList;
    private Context mContext;

    public SpecialobjectHistoryRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<SpecialobjectHistory> specialobjectHistoryList) {
        mContext = context;
        mSpecialobjectHistoryList = specialobjectHistoryList;
    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_specialobject_history_row, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindRow(mSpecialobjectHistoryList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSpecialobjectHistoryList.size();
    }

    public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public SpecialobjectHistory thisSpecialobjectHistory;
        public TextView specialobjectTimestampTextView;
        public EditText specialobjectValueEditText;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            specialobjectTimestampTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_specialobject_history_row_textview_timestamp);
            specialobjectValueEditText = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_specialobject_history_row_edittext_value);
        }

        public void bindRow(final SpecialobjectHistory specialobjectHistory) {
            thisSpecialobjectHistory = specialobjectHistory;
            specialobjectTimestampTextView.setText(specialobjectHistory.getTimestamp());
            specialobjectValueEditText.setText(specialobjectHistory.getValue() + "");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: could you share your xml code.

Comment: horizontal layout all items match parent and all items weight 1

Comment: match parent on both height and width? (edit: Using match parent definitely did not work)

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim Added XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set the width of first Textview to 0dp

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Comment: when I copied first time your cod was a match_parent, but check your code  and give it a try

Comment: The code I am using uses 0dp and it does not work. The spacing is still totally off on everything.

Comment: then we should see your RecyclerView adapter. may be the problem is programmatic.

Comment: I doubt it -- all I'm doing is setting each field using `.setText()`

Comment: did you do that for the EditText too?

Comment: Yes. I am now noticing that when I scroll down and then scroll back up, the stuff that went off-screen looks correct when it comes back on-screen. In other words everything is crushed together on first load and then it looks okay when you scroll it off and then back on.

Comment: then you should check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590957/how-to-set-text-in-an-edittext) about setText for EditText view.

Comment: Didn't seem to change anything. I'll post my adapter

Comment: Right now I am not binding/changing the third text so I'm just defaulting it to what's pre-set in the XML.

Comment: setText() for EditText takes second argument, try to change that line little to this editText.setText(specialobjectHistory.getValue() + "", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

Comment: I mentioned above that I did that, but it had no effect

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="starttext"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_weight="2" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="endingtext"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

not tested but should work

Comment: How is this any different from what I have?

Comment: android:layout_width="0dp"