# set text edittext

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm working on a QR scanner app. After a succesfull scan the scanned info goes into the alert box. From there, I need the info to go to an EditText field or skip the entire alert dialog. The result which has to go to the EditText is in the function below.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;


EditText editText;
@SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText4);


    EditText delete2;
    Button button3;



    button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    delete2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    final EditText finalEdittext = delete2;
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Clear EditText
            finalEdittext.getText().clear();

        }
    });

    EditText delete4;
    Button button4;

    delete4 = findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);

    final EditText finalEdittext1 = delete4;
    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Clear EditText
            finalEdittext1.getText().clear();

        }
    });
}


public void onClick(View v){
    mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
    setContentView(mScannerView);
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    mScannerView.startCamera();


}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();

}



@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    //handle result
    Log.v("handleResult", result.getText());


    //editText.setText(result.toString());
   // editText.invalidate();
    mScannerView.stopCamera(); //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //resume scanning
    //mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
    updateScannerData(1,result.getText());



}



public void updateScannerData(int scanType, String scannedCode){
   editText.setText(scannedCode);
   //editText.invalidate();
   //editText.requestLayout();

    //finish();
    //startActivity(getIntent());
    this.recreate();


    }
```

}

I only use one main activity and this is the XML of the EditText where the result has to go.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="197dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/scan_order"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Set Text In An EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590957/how-to-set-text-in-an-edittext)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be more then one approach here, you can :

```
Edittext edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.viewid);
edt.setText(result.getText());
```

or if you need to update this text view frequently multiple times make method inside your main activity updateScannerEditText(String value); and call it from your fragment.

In case you have handleResult() inside you main activity itself simply create method inside your activity :

```
@Override  // move your setContentView() method inside activity oncreate()
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void handleResult(Result result) {
   //handle result
Log.v("handleResult", result.getText());
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
builder.setMessage(result.getText());
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();

mScannerView.stopCamera();
updateScannerData(1,result.gettext()); 


//resume scanning
mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);

}
```

Method implementation :

```
private void updateScannerData(int scanType, String scannedCode){
edt.setText(scannedCode);//edt is the editTextView that you have declared in you xml.
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: oh great, pls thank me by accepting the answer. might help others.

Comment: it means the editText on which you are trying to set the text is null, which means it has not been initialised like > (EditText)findViewById(R.id.viewid);

Comment: no , unfortunately not the error nullpointer is gone tho , but nothing is set in edittext

Comment: okay, Step1 : make a global variable Edittext edt;
Step2: add followind line in oncreate() below setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.viewid);
where R.id.viewid is the id name defined in xml for edt.

Comment: check value of result.getText();

Comment: i think your code is different from what you have posted in question. post exact code here.

Comment: yes im still working on it so it keeps changing , ill edit to current code

Comment: i find a lot of people with kinda the same issue , i believe it is a bug in the setText() ,but who am i ? lol

Comment: thats highly unlikely.

Comment: yes , but i cant find my solution , could i be something with ui refresh ?

Comment: sahil , i discovered that if i put editText.setText("could be anything") below content view , it displays the text , it's some thing , but still dont know why my code doesn't place it in editText

Comment: simply means you are not getting value at result.getText() debug that.

Comment: how do you do that in android studio

Comment: i was looking into watches atm , but thank you , you either dont see the fix dont you ?

Answer (score 0):

So if i've understood right you're trying to scan a QR Code then you're setting it to an EditText2 and then you're scanning again a product and trying to set it in EditText4.

So just try to make somethink like this:

```
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    //handle result
    Log.v("handleResult", result.getText());

    if(edittext2.getText().equals("")){
    edittext2.setText(result.getText());
    }else{
     edittext4.setText(result.getText())
      }

    mScannerView.stopCamera(); setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //resume scanning
    mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);

}
```